# Object disappears when trying to set origin to geometry

Tags: 3d-cursor

Im trying to get the cursor to the selected object. The Cursor wont move to the selected object.
I tried resetting with all transformations, and tried origin to geometry, but my object disappears
and I get some dimensions and some type of code in the location boxes.

[image]

Comment: If you can reproduce this (possibly with different versions of Blender) you should report it as a bug. Does it happen with other objects too? What happens if you append this object to a new blend-file?

Comment: Here's the file if someone would like to take a look at it. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LwBmNOG5" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LwBmNOG5/)

Comment: Looks like a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes for me as well.

**However:**
If you go into edit mode and select all vertices via Box Select (don't use <kbd>A</kbd>), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection, you'll see that there is at least one vertex at an undefined position (nan = not a number). If you delete that, everything is back to normal.

Comment: I Followed your instructions, but that vertex doesn't seem to appear once I do the inversion. When you invert, does it show one vertex highlighted?  https://ibb.co/kx24Stj

Comment: No, you won't see anything. It's at an undefined location. Just invert the selection in then press X to delete. (You can look at the transform values and see "nan", which tells you that _something_ is selected.